# Generate City in a textbox based from zip code entered in a textbox

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, doctrine, kohana

I have two textboxes, Zip Code and City. When the user enters a Zip, the City should be automatically generated in the city textbox.

The Zip Code and City are stored in the a table in the Database. My Backend is PHP using kohana 2.3.4 framework and DoctrineORM. and My Database is MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with a javascript async httprequest.
Use javascript to detect changes in the Zipcode textbox,
create a httprequest to a second php page that takes a http variable for zip code,
let this page search the right city in the database and put in on the html as a simple text
in the http response read the html you get from the request and extract the city from it.
display the city in the right textbox.

Comment: thanks thomas it make sense, i am a newbie here, do you have links for relevant tutorials on what you are saying?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp
or take a look at this stackoverflow question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript

Comment: it may be better to update on blur() instead of when the value changes